# Join 2 other tables and 2 on conditions within those joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join, where-clause

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subscriberMaster.id,    
subscriberMaster.locationCodeID, subscriberMaster.firstName,
subscriberMaster.lastName, subscriberMaster.company, subscriberMaster.address,
subscriberMaster.address2, subscriberMaster.city, subscriberMaster.province,
subscriberMaster.postalCode, subscriberMaster.country,
subscriberMaster.numLabels
FROM subscriberMaster
JOIN commodityMaster ON commodityMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id AND
commodityMaster.commodityID IN (" . $commodityquery2 . ")
JOIN industryMaster ON industryMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id AND
industryMaster.industryID IN (" . $industryquery2 . ")
WHERE subscriberMaster.locationCodeID = $locationCodeID AND
subscriberMaster.province IN (" . $provincequery2 . ") AND
(subscriberMaster.deleted = 0) AND (subscriberMaster.expiryDate = '00-00-00')
OR (subscriberMaster.expiryDate > NOW()) ORDER BY $orderBy ASC");
```

Everything in this query was working just fine until I added a second join where it was also matching the same id from the main table. The Where clauses all works fine and the first join with both ON conditions worked. It seems to be an issue with the second JOIN clause.

Basically subscribersMaster is the main table with all the records details (address, phone number etc). CommodityMaster and IndustryMaster stores details on which industries they work in and what commodities they sell.

EDIT**
Here is what comes out when I echo the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriberMaster.id, subscriberMaster.locationCodeID,
subscriberMaster.firstName, subscriberMaster.lastName, subscriberMaster.company,
subscriberMaster.address, subscriberMaster.address2, subscriberMaster.city,
subscriberMaster.province, subscriberMaster.postalCode, subscriberMaster.country,
subscriberMaster.numLabels FROM subscriberMaster
JOIN commodityMaster ON commodityMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id
JOIN industryMaster ON industryMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id
WHERE subscriberMaster.locationCodeID = 1 AND commodityMaster.commodityID IN ('1',
'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19',
'20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33') AND
industryMaster.industryID IN ('1','3','2') subscriberMaster.province IN
('Ontario') AND (subscriberMaster.deleted = 0) AND (subscriberMaster.expiryDate =
 '00-00-00') OR (subscriberMaster.expiryDate > NOW())
ORDER BY company ASC
```

Comment: Can you provide the sql fiddle of above query with sample data set and your resultset that you want from the query

Comment: And what is the issue here? Do you get any errors or data is not returned?

Comment: No error, just nothing returned.

Answer (score 0):

I would move your additional constraint from JOIN part to WHERE part. It's the place where it should be.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    subscriberMaster.id,    
    subscriberMaster.locationCodeID, 
    subscriberMaster.firstName,
    subscriberMaster.lastName, 
    subscriberMaster.company, 
    subscriberMaster.address,
    subscriberMaster.address2, 
    subscriberMaster.city, 
    subscriberMaster.province,
    subscriberMaster.postalCode, 
    subscriberMaster.country,
    subscriberMaster.numLabels
    FROM subscriberMaster
        JOIN commodityMaster 
            ON commodityMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id 
        JOIN industryMaster 
            ON industryMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id 
    WHERE subscriberMaster.locationCodeID = $locationCodeID 
        AND commodityMaster.commodityID IN (" . $commodityquery2 . ")
        AND industryMaster.industryID IN (" . $industryquery2 . ")
        AND subscriberMaster.province IN (" . $provincequery2 . ") 
        AND (subscriberMaster.deleted = 0) 
        AND (subscriberMaster.expiryDate = '00-00-00')
        OR (subscriberMaster.expiryDate > NOW()) 
    ORDER BY $orderBy ASC
```

Comment: Still not working. I tested taking out both joins and just using one and both work on their own. But as soon as I use both they stop showing any results.

Comment: Try the statement without the WHERE clause. I would guess there is the problem...

Comment: Took out where clause and still not working. Or did you just mean take out the word WHERE and continue the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Change your industryMaster `JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and see if it returns data, i assume that you don't have rows for all `subscribermaster` id in the `industrymaster`,  try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriberMaster.id,    
subscriberMaster.locationCodeID, subscriberMaster.firstName,
subscriberMaster.lastName, subscriberMaster.company, subscriberMaster.address,
subscriberMaster.address2, subscriberMaster.city, subscriberMaster.province,
subscriberMaster.postalCode, subscriberMaster.country,
subscriberMaster.numLabels

FROM subscriberMaster
LEFT OUTER JOIN commodityMaster 
   ON commodityMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id 
   AND commodityMaster.commodityID IN (" . $commodityquery2 . ")

LEFT OUTER JOIN industryMaster 
   ON industryMaster.subscriberID = subscriberMaster.id 
   AND industryMaster.industryID IN (" . $industryquery2 . ")

WHERE subscriberMaster.locationCodeID = $locationCodeID AND
subscriberMaster.province IN (" . $provincequery2 . ") AND
(subscriberMaster.deleted = 0) AND (subscriberMaster.expiryDate = '00-00-00')
OR (subscriberMaster.expiryDate > NOW()) 
ORDER BY $orderBy ASC
```

Comment: Still not working. I tested taking out both joins and just using one and both work on their own. But as soon as I use both they stop showing any results.